# How can I implement a "did you mean" algorithm in a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, spell-checking, levenshtein-distance

I have a database that contains an ID, a name and a rating for tv shows.

I can search through it with this script:

```
import sqlite3

#Connect to database
def database_connection(sqlite_database):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_database)
    except sqlite3.error as e:
        print(e)
    return connection

#Search database with name
def search_database():
    name = input("Enter Name: ")

    #Establish database connection AND connect query executioner
    connection = database_connection('anime.sqlite')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM anime WHERE name=?", (name,))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        anime = dict(ID=row[0], name=row[1], rating=row[2])

    print(anime)

search_database()
```

So if I'm looking for "Naruto" and I end up writing "Naroto", it would look through the database and find the nearest match and give that result back.

I took a standalone script for levenshteinDistance and tried to apply it on a simple list and it looks like this (works perfectly fine):

```
anime_names = ['Naruto Shippuden', 'Boruto', 'Naruto']

word1 = 'Naroto'

def levenshteinDistance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > len(s2):
        s1, s2 = s2, s1

    distances = range(len(s1) + 1)
    for i2, c2 in enumerate(s2):
        distances_ = [i2+1]
        for i1, c1 in enumerate(s1):
            if c1 == c2:
                distances_.append(distances[i1])
            else:
                distances_.append(1 + min((distances[i1], distances[i1 + 1], distances_[-1])))
        distances = distances_
    return distances[-1]

scores = {}

for i in anime_names:
    scores[i] = 1 - levenshteinDistance(word1, i)

print(max(scores, key=scores.get))
```

> Naruto

So I'm lost on how I would substitute that mock-example with a small list for a search/comparison of all the names found in the database. How would I integrate it into the database script above.

Comment: The standard way of solving this is to use a module like the [spellfix](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) loadable module, however that'll require compiling and loading the module before the SQL examples will work.

Comment: I guess what I'll do is keep all names in memory in a list and use the levenshtein distance algorithm on that instead. Only access it when the user has an error in the name.